# Creating a page from acf fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a number of acf fields(advanced custom field), that have different fields, text, etc. 
I wanna know if it is possible to create a page for each field repeater, which will use a certain template, when the fields are saved ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. That being said, it's probably possible, but have you tried anything or have code to share of your attempts?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not try anything yet, because I can't find the logic at the moment, on how to create, a page or post, for those fields on save. My project in based on apartments and projects, each project has any number of apartments, and I gotta create links for the project fields, text,img, etc, and also for the apartment ones.

Comment: Why do you want to do this using ACF and not a Custom Post Type?

Comment: ACF adds fields to a page (or post, or custom post type). It doesn't have anything built-in that would create separate pages/URLs for any of its content. You probably really want to create a CPT, or multiple CPTs, and custom taxonomies to get your basic page functionality set and from there you can use ACF for details like square footage, price, etc. that don't need their own link but are required for each Apartment CPT.

Comment: Agreed that a custom post type is the ideal structure for this.  Taxonomy for classification, custom fields and content for the details.

Comment: The admin, will add the structure of the projects apartments, so I thought, it will be easier for him, if I add a section in the admin, to create them.

Comment: Should I create a custom post type and insert the fields acf fields into it ?

Comment: And also, it is possible to create a view that includes all of this, and creates 2 types of pages one for the project and one for the apartment ?